# ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json

Tags: sql, json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm getting the error
`ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`

when launching the SQL query

```
update pdfs
set forced_payload = datatable.forced_payload,
    s3_original_path = datatable.s3_original_path,
    s3_image_path = datatable.s3_image_path,
    s3_preview_path = datatable.s3_preview_path,
    s3_original_inbox_path = datatable.s3_original_inbox_path,
    s3_preview_inbox_path = datatable.s3_preview_inbox_path
from (select 43238::integer as id,
             NULL::json as forced_payload,
             NULL::character varying(255) as s3_original_path,
             NULL::character varying(255) as s3_image_path,
             NULL::character varying(255) as s3_preview_path,
             NULL::character varying(255) as s3_original_inbox_path,
             NULL::character varying(255) as s3_preview_inbox_path
      union
      select 43239,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL
     ) as datatable
where pdfs.id = datatable.id;
```

against a postregSQL DB

I have no idea why i'm getting this error.
I've seen other posts with this error, but they were related to the use of `DISTINCT` or `GROUP_BY` which is not the case here.

For more context :

I've got a rails project with the gem [bulk_data_methods](https://github.com/fiksu/bulk_data_methods) in order to update multiple records in DB with only one DB query.

This is the gem that is creating the DB query mentioned above.

(and the complete error in rails is :
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the `UNION`. To calculate `UNION`, PostgreSQL has to remove duplicates, which it cannot do without a notion of equality. Use `UNION ALL`, then PostgreSQL does not try to remove duplicates.

Comment: thanks ! it was the problem and the correct solution (using `UNION ALL`)
(I just had to make sure myself that there were no duplicates)